# How to deal with empty List in Parse

Tags: android, textview, parse-platform

Im using parse and sometimes my query will return an empty list. I want to be able to handle this condition by showing a text in the text view. The code seems to be working fine when the list does return objects but not when the list is empty. Not sure what the error but the app crashes.

```
public class ReviewPage extends Activity {
    String obj, rName, rating, reviews;
    TextView txtview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_review_page);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        obj = i.getStringExtra("RestName");
        txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.review1);
        getReview(obj);
    }

    public void getReview(String obj) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Reviews");
        query.whereEqualTo("Restraunt", obj);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> reviewList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    ParseObject review = reviewList.get(0);
                    if (review == null) {
                        txtview.setText("No Reviews yet");
                    } else {
                        rName = review.getString("Name");
                        rating = review.getString("Rating");
                        reviews = review.getString("review");
                        txtview.setText(rName + "\n" + reviews);
                    }
                } else {
                    txtview.setText("No Reviews yet");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void Submit(View v) {
        final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.review);
        final EditText edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rName);
        String rName = edit1.getText().toString();
        String review = edit.getText().toString();

        ParseObject newReview = new ParseObject("Reviews");
        newReview.put("Name", rName);
        newReview.put("review", review);
        newReview.put("Restraunt", obj);
        newReview.saveInBackground();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.review_page, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app is crashing because you're trying to get an item from an empty list (As you said, Parse is returning an empty list), which would throw a `IndexOutOFBoundException`. If I were you, I'd add a null check and an empty check before doing something with the ParseObject list. Something like this would do:

```
    if (e == null) {
       if(reviewList!=null && !reviewList.isEmpty()){
          ParseObject review = reviewList.get(0);
          if (review == null) {
             txtview.setText("No Reviews yet");
             } else {
                 rName = review.getString("Name");
                 rating = review.getString("Rating");
                 reviews = review.getString("review");
                 txtview.setText(rName + "\n" + reviews);
             }
          } else { 
               // reviewList is empty. 
                 }
       } else {
              txtview.setText("No Reviews yet");
              e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app obviously crashes on `ParseObject review = reviewList.get(0);` line, because you cannot get an element out of zero-length array.
*The simplest solution:* you add a TextView with an error message text before the ListView in `layout.xml`. When the list is empty, set TextView visibility to VISIBLE, GONE otherwise (or change text in displayed TextView accordingly.)

```
    if (reviewList.size() == 0) {
        txtview.setText("No Reviews yet");
    } else {
        ParseObject review = reviewList.get(0);
        ...
    }
```